# Opening Sharepoint Document Error 52

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I tried to use the code I found https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174690/open-file-in-a-sharepoint-list-via-vba

My goal is to save the document in the users temp folder and then open it. However I am getting

> error 52

on the FileCopy line. I copied the sharepoint link directly off of the email link so it should be exactly accurate.

I referred to many questions on here regarding FileCopy Error 52, but was unable to find a relevant answer.

If it is possible to open the document without saving that would actually be preferable, but I cannot use the Microsoft Scripting Runtime as some individuals are on Macintosh computers that do not have that library. The solutions I found that were a straight open seemed to all require that which is why I am saving and then opening.

```
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim strName As String
 Dim URL As String

 strFolder = Environ("temp")
 strName = "\QpiExport.xlsx"
 URL = "https://sharepoint.company.com/some/more/files/Shared%20Documents/QSPI%20Export/QpiExport.xlsx"

 If Dir(strFolder & strName) <> "" Then ' if the temp file already exists then delete it first
  VBA.SetAttr strFolder & strName, vbNormal ' remove any file attributes (e.g. read-only) that would block the kill command
  VBA.Kill strFolder & strName ' delete the file
 End If

 FileCopy URL, strFolder & strName
 Workbooks.Open strFolder & strName
```

Comment: You need a separator "\" between strFolder and strName.

Comment: @Andy G Swapped it to be strFolder & "\" & strName, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: You need to do it in all five places. Preferably, construct a variable.

Comment: Added it to the start of strName. , same error. (Thank you though!)

Comment: Print out the value of `Environ("temp")`, is it what it should be? I.e. a valid path that you can append a filename to?

Comment: In Locals it shows as "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp" which should be a valid path.

Comment: @AndyG I tried changing it to Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop", but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by someone at work:

I needed to use the following filepath for the sharepoint which differed from the web address.

```
  URL= "\\sharepoint.company.com@SSL\SomethingRoot\a\few\folders\Shared Documents\QSPI Export\QpiExport.xlsx"
```